# Modifying API Base URL Prefix for WordPress REST API

Tags: php, wordpress, routes, slug, wordpress-rest-api

I've examined [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37265427/how-to-modify-wordpress-rest-api-response), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43629677/custom-url-wordpress-rest-api) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45442275/wordpress-rest-api-url-decoding) and more.

The best example I found was replacing the "wp-json" slug (which I can't add code here right now).

```
localhost/wp-json/wp/v2
localhost/api/wp/v2
```

While you can make a change like above. So how can we change the rest of the URL? Okay, I'm not saying "endpoint" or "route" change. I'm still talking about a prefix change.

Ok this way was very good: `localhost/api/wp/v2` well how do we change the `wp/v2`? Can you actually do something like `localhost/api/posts` if you look at it? Because we want to remove `wp/v2`.

Well, it's also possible: `localhost/api/any/posts`.